# Ismember by row in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to figure out a matrix-oriented way to perform the ismember function by row in MATLAB. That is, if I have matrices

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
[7 8 9 10 11 12]
```

And I put in

```
[3 4 5]
[10 11 12]
```

Into some ismember-ish function, I'd like it to return

```
[0 0 1 1 1 0]
[0 0 0 1 1 1]
```

Other than looping over each row of the matrix in a for loop, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are `[1 2 3 4 5 6] [7 8 9 10 11 12]` 2 rows of the same matrix?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: good question - if the answer's yes, the solution is a lot simpler.

Comment: Does this need to match the ordered pattern, of the second input, or only the elements.  That is, would the answer be different if you put in `[5 4 3]`, rather than `[3 4 5]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your data are available as matrices `A` and `B`

```
A = [
    1 2 3 4 5 6
    7 8 9 10 11 12
    ];

B = [
    3 4 5
    10 11 12];
```

you can convert them to cells and then use `cellfun`

```
cellA = mat2cell(A, ones(1, size(A,1)), size(A,2));
cellB = mat2cell(B, ones(1, size(B,1)), size(B,2));

membership = cell2mat(cellfun(@ismember, cellA, cellB, 'UniformOutput',  false));
```

This returns

```
membership =

     0     0     1     1     1     0
     0     0     0     1     1     1
```

Comment: Excellent. Haven't had a chance to test it yet, but this seems like exactly what I need. Thank you.

Comment: That does return the same value as if a for loop is used, but it isn't a "matrix" solution. As a cell, it internally loops over every row of the cell. Therefore, it is just as slow as using a for loop. A matrix solution should be a one-step process, executing much faster than a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [5 3 4 2]; B = [2 4 4 4 6 8];
[Lia1,Locb1] = ismember(A,B)

Lia1 =

 1     1     1     1     0     0


 Locb1 =

 4     3     3     3     0     0
```